# The problem of the relationship in Mysql, doctrine gets this error: Doctrine_Table_Exception: Unknown relation alias Model_Training

Tags: doctrine, relational-database

I have a problem with relationships in the Doctrine. Works on Mysql database. The problem occurs when downloading data using the relationship throws me this error: **Doctrine_Table_Exception: Unknown relation alias Model_Training**

Please help me get tired of it some days I sit on it and nothing came up, and google also did not find anything.

**Here is the code that retrieves data:**

```
$dataRows = Doctrine_Query::create()
                    ->from('Model_Training a')->where('a.idTrainings = ?', $this->_getParam('id'))
                    ->leftJoin('a.Model_TrainingBonuse ac')
                    ->leftJoin('a.Model_Bonuse ad')
                    ->fetchArray();
```

**Schema.yml file with the formation of models for the Doctrine:**

```
TrainingBonuse:
  tableName: Trainings_has_Bonuses
  columns:
    Trainings_idTrainings:
      type: integer(4)
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: true
    Bonuses_idBonuses:
      type: integer(4)
      notnull: true
  relations:
    TrainingsIdTraining:
      class: Training
      local: Trainings_idTrainings
      foreign: idTrainings
      foreignAlias: Trainings_has_Bonuses
    BonusesIdBonuse:
      class: Bonuse
      local: Bonuses_idBonuses
      foreign: idBonuses
      foreignAlias: Trainings_has_Bonuses
  indexes:
    fk_Trainings_has_Bonuses_Bonuses1:
      fields: [Bonuses_idBonuses]
    fk_Trainings_has_Bonuses_Trainings1:
      fields: [Trainings_idTrainings]
  options:
    charset: utf8
    collate: utf8_polish_ci

Bonuse:
  tableName: Bonuses
  columns:
    idBonuses:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: true
    name:
      type: string(45)
    title:
      type: string(255)
    description:
      type: clob(65535)
    file_url_full:
      type: string(255)
    file_type:
      type: integer(1)
    width_full:
      type: integer(4)
    height_full:
      type: integer(4)
    active:
      type: integer(1)
      default: 1
  options:
    charset: utf8
    collate: utf8_polish_ci

Training:
  tableName: Trainings
  columns:
    idTrainings:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: true
    title:
      type: string(255)
    sub_title:
      type: string(255)
    up_body:
      type: clob(65535)
    training_body:
      type: clob(65535)
    question:
      type: clob(65535)
    opinion:
      type: clob(65535)
    bonuses:
      type: integer(1)
      notnull: true
      default: 0
    down_body:
      type: clob(65535)
    modyfication:
      type: integer(1)
      notnull: true
      default: 0
    active:
      type: integer(1)
      notnull: true
      default: 1
  options:
    charset: utf8
    collate: utf8_polish_ci
```

**Models:**
TRAINING

```
abstract class Model_Base_Training extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->setTableName('Trainings');
        $this->hasColumn('idTrainings', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'primary' => true,
             'autoincrement' => true,
             'length' => '4',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('title', 'string', 255, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'length' => '255',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('sub_title', 'string', 255, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'length' => '255',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('up_body', 'clob', 65535, array(
             'type' => 'clob',
             'length' => '65535',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('training_body', 'clob', 65535, array(
             'type' => 'clob',
             'length' => '65535',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('question', 'clob', 65535, array(
             'type' => 'clob',
             'length' => '65535',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('opinion', 'clob', 65535, array(
             'type' => 'clob',
             'length' => '65535',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('bonuses', 'integer', 1, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'notnull' => true,
             'default' => 0,
             'length' => '1',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('down_body', 'clob', 65535, array(
             'type' => 'clob',
             'length' => '65535',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('modyfication', 'integer', 1, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'notnull' => true,
             'default' => 0,
             'length' => '1',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('active', 'integer', 1, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'notnull' => true,
             'default' => 1,
             'length' => '1',
             ));

        $this->option('collate', 'utf8_polish_ci');
        $this->option('charset', 'utf8');
        $this->option('type', 'InnoDB');
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->hasMany('Model_UserTraining as Users_has_Trainings', array(
             'local' => 'idTrainings',
             'foreign' => 'Trainings_idTrainings'));

        $this->hasMany('Model_TrainingBonuse as Trainings_has_Bonuses', array(
             'local' => 'idTrainings',
             'foreign' => 'Trainings_idTrainings'));
    }
}
```

TRAINING_BONUSES

```
abstract class Model_Base_TrainingBonuse extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->setTableName('Trainings_has_Bonuses');
        $this->hasColumn('Trainings_idTrainings', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => true,
             'length' => '4',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('Bonuses_idBonuses', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'notnull' => true,
             'length' => '4',
             ));


        $this->index('fk_Trainings_has_Bonuses_Bonuses1', array(
             'fields' => 
             array(
              0 => 'Bonuses_idBonuses',
             ),
             ));
        $this->index('fk_Trainings_has_Bonuses_Trainings1', array(
             'fields' => 
             array(
              0 => 'Trainings_idTrainings',
             ),
             ));
        $this->option('collate', 'utf8_polish_ci');
        $this->option('charset', 'utf8');
        $this->option('type', 'InnoDB');
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->hasOne('Model_Training as TrainingsIdTraining', array(
             'local' => 'Trainings_idTrainings',
             'foreign' => 'idTrainings'));

        $this->hasOne('Model_Bonuse as BonusesIdBonuse', array(
             'local' => 'Bonuses_idBonuses',
             'foreign' => 'idBonuses'));
    }
}
```

BONUSES

```
abstract class Model_Base_Bonuse extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->setTableName('Bonuses');
        $this->hasColumn('idBonuses', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'primary' => true,
             'autoincrement' => true,
             'length' => '4',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('name', 'string', 45, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'length' => '45',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('title', 'string', 255, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'length' => '255',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('description', 'clob', 65535, array(
             'type' => 'clob',
             'length' => '65535',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('file_url_full', 'string', 255, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'length' => '255',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('file_type', 'integer', 1, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'length' => '1',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('width_full', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'length' => '4',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('height_full', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'length' => '4',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('active', 'integer', 1, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'default' => 1,
             'length' => '1',
             ));

        $this->option('collate', 'utf8_polish_ci');
        $this->option('charset', 'utf8');
        $this->option('type', 'InnoDB');
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->hasMany('Model_TrainingBonuse as Trainings_has_Bonuses', array(
             'local' => 'idBonuses',
             'foreign' => 'Bonuses_idBonuses'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "Model_Training" table definition in your schema.yml file...theres "Training" though... If there's no "alias class" or "foreign alias" element specified in your schema.yml, table definition's name is used. So instead of "Model_Training" use "Training" (this applies to "Model_Bonuses" and others too).